# Why call not empty setState()?

Tags: flutter

Why Flutter defines that we should call:

```
setState(() { _counter++});
```

instead of:

```
_counter++;
setState(() {});
```

As far as I can see in `setState()` code, it doesn't use anything that's passed as a parameter anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The end result in release mode is the same.

But in debug you get an assert for free that checks that the callback inside `setState()` does not return a `Future` and it returns immediately.

But if you are sure the callback is synchronous, the result in debug is the same.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't get why to force people to pass something to `setState()`... If it was called `invalidateState()` and before calling it we set all the necessary variables, call all the Futures we want, won't it be the same?

Comment: Well, they don't force you. It is a best practice to avoid te asynchronous problems. But since you can set it outside and it works, you can do it.